# Aggregation of a table using xPath in xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPATH and I have an XML document that contains a table. I was wondering if it's possible to aggregate the rows that have the same name and add up the other values.

Here is my XML table:

```
  <Table Type="Main">
      <Line>
        <R1>
          <Name>Jane</Name>
          <Orders>12</Orders></Line>
      <Line>
        <R1>
          <Name>Mark</Name>
          <Orders>7</Orders></Line>
      <Line>
        <R1>
          <Name>Jane</Name>
          <Orders>11</Orders></R1></Line>
      <Line>
        <R1>
          <Name>Adam</Name>
          <Orders>17</Orders></R1></Line>
      <Line></Table>
```

And I would like for the results to be something like this:

| Name | Order |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | 23 |
| Mark | 7 |
| Adam | 17 |

Is this even possible in only using xPath or would I need to modify the source table, thanks.

Comment: What is your XPath version?

Comment: Are you trying to convert your XML to an HTML table, or some kind of tabular data like CSV/TSV?

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard grouping problem. I would strongly recommend using XSLT 2.0+ for the job rather than pure XPath: XPath can select and aggregate data from an input XML but it can't construct a new XML tree to represent the result table.

The core of the solution in XSLT 2.0 is:

```
<table>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="//Line" group-by="R1/Name">
     <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/R1/Orders)"/></td>
     </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 3 you could do something like this:

```bash
fold-left(//R1, map{}, function($map, $r1) {
    map:put($map, $r1/Name, sum( ($r1/Orders, map:get($map, $r1/Name)) ))
})
```

which results in:

```bash
map{"Jane": 23, "Mark": 7, "Adam": 17}
```

Now, if you need a tabular output then you might do:

```bash
//R1
=> fold-left(map{"Name":"Order"}, function($map,$r1) {
       map:put($map, $r1/Name, sum( ($r1/Orders, map:get($map, $r1/Name)) ))
   })
=> map:for-each(concat(?, codepoints-to-string(9), ?))
=> string-join(codepoints-to-string(10))
```

<sup>**note:** this solution isn't fully correct (no TSV escaping, possible conflict of a name with the header, ...) but shows the workflow for generating a TSV</sup>

```
Name    Order
Jane    23
Mark    7
Adam    17
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 1.0 it's possible to sum values. The grouping key (Name) should be known in advance however

```
xmllint --xpath 'sum(//R1[Name[.="Jane"]]/Orders)' tmp.xml
23

xmllint --xpath 'sum(//R1[Name[.="Adam"]]/Orders)' tmp.xml
17
```